# org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to All.User

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Hi i have been getting a ClassCastException when trying to get the active username that is logged in.

Error below-

```
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to All.User
```

The method where the error is coming from is:

```
    public String getCurrentUser(){
          String username;
          Object user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
          if(user instanceof UserDetails){
                username = ((UserDetails) user).getUsername();
            }
            else{
                username = "";
            }
            return username;

        }
```

I have a UserServiceImpl class:

```
@Component
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private UserRoleRepository roleRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        user.setPass(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPass()));
        user.setRole(new ArrayList<>((Collection<? extends UserRole>) roleRepository.findAll()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

}
```

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name ="pass")
    private String pass;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address; 

    @Column(name = "telephone")
    private long phone;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    List<AuctionItem>itemList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    List<ItemSold>purchaseList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    List<UserRole> role;

    private String passwordConfirm;

    public List<AuctionItem> getItemList() {
        return itemList;
    }

    public void setItemList(List<AuctionItem> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }

    public List<ItemSold> getPurchaseList() {
        return purchaseList;
    }

    public void setPurchaseList(List<ItemSold> purchaseList) {
        this.purchaseList = purchaseList;
    }

    public List<UserRole> getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(List<UserRole> role) {
        this.role = role;
    }



    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public long getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(long phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPasswordConfirm() {
        return passwordConfirm;
    }

    public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm) {
        this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
    }


}
```

Any ideas of what the problem could be?

Comment: @jmw5598 All is the source package and User is the entity class

Comment: If you want to use your User class with spring security, you will need to implement Spring Securities `UserDetails` interface

Comment: @jmw5598 ok thanks this makes sense, however i was using this tutorial when setting up my login process - https://hellokoding.com/registration-and-login-example-with-spring-security-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-hsql-jsp/ and it appears that the example code doesnt use implements UserDetails, do you know why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139689/discussion-between-jmw5598-and-hazardaguess).